# Server Raw HTTP response from file

Tags: node.js

I have two files on disk. One which contains the exact HTTP headers I want to respond with and one which contains the raw HTTP body that I want to return.

What's the easiest way to have node return these two files so that it looks like a normal HTTP response to the caller.

I don't want to parse the file and then call res.writeHead() or something like that. I just want to tell node, here's the exact data I want you to push back to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Use a plain TCP server instead of an HTTP server? If you need to parse the request still, you could use node's HTTP parser binding directly (see [http.js](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.10/lib/http.js#L29) in node core).